# How to open registry files for reading (c++)

Tags: c++, window, registry

I am trying to find a way to create a c++ program (for live forensic analysis purposes), that can read Windows registry file(s) (e.g. SAM, Software, Amcache.hve etc.) from running system. Example of the filepath - *C:\Windows\System32\config\Software*.
I have already tried several options (ifstream, filesystem, CFile, File System Redirector, also with administrator privileges), but nothing worked for me. So I am beginng to wonder, if it is even possible to read these system files. Or I have to use something like this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2017/may/c-use-modern-c-to-access-the-windows-registry.
If anyone has any clue on how to do it, please let me know.
I am thankful for every piece of information in advance.

Edit:
As comments suggested, there is a way using Windows API (but maybe without Amcache.hve). The main question is still unanswered, if it is even possible to read these files without Windows API (maybe through NTFS?).

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regloadkeyw

Comment: Have you tried the [standard Windows API functions for accessing the Windows Registry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/registry-functions)? If you did, then please explain in detail what functionality you require that is not provided by this API.

Comment: Ok, I tried it, but for example Ntuser.dat and UsrClass.dat are grouped together under HKEY_CURRENT_USER and is there a way to also access Amcache.hve? And the second question is, can I somehow get a content of registry files without using Windows API?

Comment: @jeff12863: I suggest that you [edit] the question to update it with the information in your previous comment. All important information should be in the question itself. I don't think it is possible to read those files while the operating system is running, because (1) they are probably locked by the operating system, and (2) they may be in an inconsistent state while the system is running. However, I do not know the exact answers to your questions, because I have no experience with the Windows Registry, except for using it through the Windows API.